# How to issue persistent commands on D-Link routers with factory firmware?

Tags: linux, command-line, wireless-router, telnet, persistent

I recently bought a D-Link DIR-822 router and I can telnet into it and issue Linux commands. The thing is, say I issued random commands like;

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 23 -j DROP
```

It works, but after reboot, everything goes back/changes to default. I tried editing the `/etc/hosts` file as well for some ad blocking, but it just changes back to default on reboot.

There's of course OpenWrt that could do the job right, but I was wondering if it was possible to do it on the stock firmware version.

Comment: Can you find out more about the linux version the thing is running? Does it have a `/etc/lsb-release` file? Or anything `*release*` under `/etc`?

Comment: Did you try normal unix-y things like seeing which filesystems are mounted read-only vs. read/write, and see if you can remount them read/write? Or look into which filesystems are RAM-based vs. flash-based?

Comment: @tink fun fact there are no /etc/lsb-release file